# How to view SMB share file history in Fedora 39

Tags: fedora, samba, smb

I've got some SMB shares mounted through fstab. The shares themselves are hosted on a TrueNAS Scale machine. My computer is running Fedora 39.

The NAS is configured to regularly take snapshots of my shares and expose them over SMB. On my Windows machines I can browse the file history either per-file via the properties view of a file, or browse the entire share at another point in time.

Ideally, I'd also have access to similar functionality in Fedora.

Is such functionality available? Ideally in Nautilus but if that's not possible I don't mind using an alternative.

Thanks